# CSS - Height of div = 100%, -20px

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I've read some other people have had this problem, but they either resorted to JS or the solution just wouldn't work for me.

I have this:

```
// The Header //
/*            */
/*  CONTENT   */
/*            */
// The footer //
```

Currently the work in progress can be found at:
http://newsite.carlsimmons.co.uk/

It's working as intended, apart from the always present vertical scroll bar. This is because the content's height is set to 100%, +header & footer height and you're left with something always bigger than the page.

I have tried the absolute option (among plenty of others), but they all have faults or don't work. Just thinking there must be some way to achieve this surely? I guess I shouldn't be too afraid of using JS for this, since it would still look fine for people with JS, but not exactly good practice and might cause some lag on browser resizing.

Comment: I think you can find some ideas here:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Why is it necessary for the content area to be 100%?

Comment: @biziclop I tried this but I have a different setup.

Comment: By the way...http://newsite.carlsimmons.co.uk/ gets a "Failed to open page" error by Safari.

Comment: Ex : <div style="height: calc(100% - 60px);" > </div>
Make sure provide spaces while usinc calc()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% -20px)`

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

But for now its only Firefox compatible 
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/

EDIT : IE 9 was the first major browser to implement calc() (cf Andy E's comment)

Comment: *'it's only Firefox compatible'* — this may surprise you, but IE 9 was the first major browser to implement `calc()`.

Comment: Haha, yeah, surprised when I read that :P I think I'm going to have to go with the above solution. Hoping webkit will one day pick it up and there we go, progressive enhancement :P After spending around 5 hours on this headache, time to realise there isn't a perfect solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You shouln't end up with a bigger page if you use a sticky footer.

One possible solution:

```
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
}
```

Another one:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;}
```

Comment: This would work ordinarily, but I have a header, which is pushing the content section (100% height) down.

Answer (score 0):

Give your header and footer absolute position and give your body top and bottom margin equal to the heights of your header and footer respectively:

```
body {
    margin: 70px 0 110px;
}
body > header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
body > footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained why absolute positioning hasn't worked for you.  Without javascript, having a fixed/absolute position is the only way to go.  Here's what I did to get it to work for me.

Basically you have your footer with your footer stuff.  Then you have a spacer to prevent the body from being fully hidden behind it.

If you want a fixed header you can do the same thing - real header that's fixed and a header spacer.

Then remove the content height because you don't need it anymore.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer_spacer">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="footer">
  footer content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer
{
  bottom:           0;
  position:         fixed;
  width:            100%;
  z-index:          1000;
}

.footer_spacer
{
  height: 25px; /* you need to make this the same height as the footer */
}
```

Comment: Or you could set the padding/margin on your wrapper/body instead of having a footer_spacer I'd imagine. Sadly this won't work for me.

Comment: Absolute won't work for me, because if I set everything up right (afaik) then the content section can go so small that it no longer wraps the actual content (its children). Fixed just provides grass at the bottom of the page no matter the scroll position, which is just strange.

Comment: "grass at the bottom" is how most desktop applications work including browsers up until the last year - known as the status bar.  You can also see it on facebook and other sites.  If it wasn't for the no javascript requirement you could show the footer when the scrollbar got to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, loads of sites use Fixed, but just wasn't the behaviour I wanted. I wanted the footers position to be affected by the height of the content above it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the `box-sizing` property:

```
height: 100%
padding: 20px 0;
-moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
     box-sizing: padding-box;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

Supported by sane browsers and IE8+ too.